# how to refresh table jquery mobile without data-role="table"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table

I am working on table in html how can i refresh the table. Im not using data-role="table" for some reason here is working
 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/YxD62/#base)

code

```
 <table id="tblMailMod" class="table  ui-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="setImg(this);">
                <td>
                    <img class="imgOk" id="envelope1" src="http://m.jalf.com/testjalf/img/select_ok.png" alt="" />
                </td>
                <td> <a data-prefetch="true" onclick="">
              <div class=" ">de:</div><div class=" ">suject:</div><div class=" ">date:</div></a>
                </td>
                <td> <a data-prefetch="true" onclick=""><span class="larrow">
                    <img class="imgArrow" src="http://m.jalf.com/testjalf/img/arrow_list_go.png"/>  </span>
                  <span>
                    <div class=" ">Admin </div>
                    <div class=" "> approuvé!</div>
                    <div class="coldate">Fri, 21 Feb 2014 18:34:47 GMT</div>
                  </span>
                </a>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: In the error console: `Error: cannot call methods on table prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`. Since you are not providing `data-role="table"`, the widget is not created automatically. You will have to do that yourself on page creation.

Comment: actually im maintaining code if i use data-role="table" i have to edit css from scratch. any other way or what you recommend

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If specifying `data-role="table"` forces you to edit CSS, instantiating the widget yourself will result in the same issue.

Comment: you want to convert current table into jQM table?

Comment: yes i want to change current table into jqm table but adding data-role="table" in <table> the page crashes. see jsfiddle link

Comment: you cant use `.table()` on none `data-role=table`. plus you dont need to _refresh_ table after changing _img_. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YxD62/2/

Comment: When i add static rows your code is working fine but   adding dyncamically dont work

Comment: because you're using inline Javascript. Delegate event to `tr`. `$(document).on("click", "tr", function () { setImg(this); });`

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I really appriciate